# asp.net web application: Invalid postback or callback argument error on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on developing an asp.net web application page with a set of cascading drop downs, text boxes and buttons on my page. The drop down lists are populated from the database and are dependent on previous drop downs. The buttons are supposed to write the selected values from the drop down and text boxes to the database.

The page gets loaded with the correct DDL lists. It works fine to write to the database if I only enter a value in the text box and click on the button.

It returns the following error if I select a value from the drop down list and enter a value in the text box and then click the button to add values to the database.

Error message:
"Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation."

I did some research and understand there can be security implications if I set enableEventValidation="false", so I don't want to use that option. 
What is the other option? How do I use  ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method as suggested in the error message?

Here is the code I am using: Since it is still under development, I have not added any validations on the DDL or Text Boxes, which I intend to do eventually.

newlevel.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" `AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="newlevels.aspx.cs" Inherits="COA.newlevels" `%>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%--<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>--%>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Totaling Level A</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTotalingLevelA" runat="server" Width="250" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTotalingLevelA_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cdlTotalingLevelA" TargetControlID="ddlTotalingLevelA" PromptText="Select Totaling Level A"
                            PromptValue="" ServicePath="ServiceCS.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetLevelAList" runat="server"
                            Category="TOTALING_LEVEL_A" LoadingText="Loading..." />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Totaling Level B</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTotalingLevelB" runat="server" Width="250"></asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cdlTotalingLevelB" TargetControlID="ddlTotalingLevelB" PromptText="Select Totaling Level B"
                            PromptValue="" ServicePath="ServiceCS.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetLevelBList"   runat="server"
                            Category="TOTALING_LEVEL_B" ParentControlID="ddlTotalingLevelA" LoadingText="Loading..." />
                    </td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalingLevelB" runat="server" required></asp:TextBox></td>
                     <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="ButtonTotalingLevelB" runat="server" Text="Add New Totaling Level B" OnClick="ButtonTotalingLevelB_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Totaling Level C</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTotalingLevelC" runat="server" Width="250"></asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cdlTotalingLevelC" TargetControlID="ddlTotalingLevelC" PromptText="Select Totaling Level C"
                            PromptValue="" ServicePath="ServiceCS.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetLevelCList"   runat="server"
                            Category="TOTALING_LEVEL_C" ParentControlID="ddlTotalingLevelB" LoadingText="Loading..." />
                    </td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalingLevelC" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                     <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="ButtonTotalingLevelC" runat="server" Text="Add New Totaling Level C" OnClick="ButtonTotalingLevelC_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Totaling Level D</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTotalingLevelD" runat="server" Width="250"></asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cdlTotalingLevelD" TargetControlID="ddlTotalingLevelD" PromptText="Select Totaling Level D"
                            PromptValue="" ServicePath="ServiceCS.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetLevelDList"   runat="server"
                            Category="TOTALING_LEVEL_D" ParentControlID="ddlTotalingLevelC" LoadingText="Loading..." />
                    </td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalingLevelD" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                     <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="ButtonTotalingLevelD" runat="server" Text="Add New Totaling Level D" OnClick="ButtonTotalingLevelD_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Totaling Level E</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTotalingLevelE" runat="server" Width="250"></asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cdlTotalingLevelE" TargetControlID="ddlTotalingLevelE" PromptText="Select Totaling Level E"
                            PromptValue="" ServicePath="ServiceCS.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetLevelEList"   runat="server"
                            Category="TOTALING_LEVEL_E" ParentControlID="ddlTotalingLevelD" LoadingText="Loading..." />
                    </td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalingLevelE" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                     <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="ButtonTotalingLevelE" runat="server" Text="Add New Totaling Level E" OnClick="ButtonTotalingLevelE_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Totaling Level F</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTotalingLevelF" runat="server" Width="250"></asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cdlTotalingLevelF" TargetControlID="ddlTotalingLevelF" 
                            PromptValue="" ServicePath="ServiceCS.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetLevelFList"   runat="server"
                            Category="TOTALING_LEVEL_F" ParentControlID="ddlTotalingLevelE" LoadingText="Loading..." />
                    </td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalingLevelF" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                     <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="ButtonTotalingLevelF" runat="server" Text="Add New Totaling Level F" OnClick="ButtonTotalingLevelF_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>


            </table>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

newlevels.aspx.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace ChartOfAccounts
{
    public partial class newlevels : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Chpcs"].ToString());
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ButtonTotalingLevelB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [SCM].[LKP_TOTALING_LEVEL_B]([TOTALING_LEVEL_B],[TOTALING_LEVEL_A],[UNARY_OPERATOR],[SORTINGORDER]) VALUES('" + ddlTotalingLevelB.SelectedItem.Value + "','" + txtTotalingLevelB.Text + "','" + "','0')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                connection.Close();

        }


        protected void ButtonTotalingLevelC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [SCM].[LKP_TOTALING_LEVEL_B]([TOTALING_LEVEL_B],[TOTALING_LEVEL_A],[UNARY_OPERATOR],[SORTINGORDER]) VALUES('" + ddlTotalingLevelC.Text + "','" + txtTotalingLevelC.Text + "','" + "','0')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();
        }

        protected void ButtonTotalingLevelD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [SCM].[LKP_TOTALING_LEVEL_B]([TOTALING_LEVEL_B],[TOTALING_LEVEL_A],[UNARY_OPERATOR],[SORTINGORDER]) VALUES('" + ddlTotalingLevelD.Text + "','" + txtTotalingLevelD.Text + "','" + "','0')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();
        }

        protected void ButtonTotalingLevelE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [SCM].[LKP_TOTALING_LEVEL_B]([TOTALING_LEVEL_B],[TOTALING_LEVEL_A],[UNARY_OPERATOR],[SORTINGORDER]) VALUES('" + ddlTotalingLevelE.Text + "','" + txtTotalingLevelE.Text + "','" + "','0')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();
        }

        protected void ButtonTotalingLevelF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [SCM].[LKP_TOTALING_LEVEL_B]([TOTALING_LEVEL_B],[TOTALING_LEVEL_A],[UNARY_OPERATOR],[SORTINGORDER]) VALUES('" + ddlTotalingLevelF.Text + "','" + txtTotalingLevelF.Text + "','" + "','0')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();
        }

        protected void ddlTotalingLevelA_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you changing the contents of any controls (like drop downs) on the client side, and then submitting the form thereafter? If so, that's why the validation exception is firing. ASP.NET will check to see if the value associated with the event argument really came from the element that rendered them; it assumes the input is malevolent otherwise.

Comment: yes, the values in the drop down are dependent on previous drop down selections. if I select a values in dropdown1 then the values on dropdown2  list change. how do I make it work with this functionality?

Comment: Have you mean cascading dropdownlists? Seems that you've missed `IsPostBack` check on `Page_Load` method, try adding it first. If the problem still persists, change all `asp:Button` to `asp:LinkButton` or use `asp:UpdatePanel` as wrapper to dropdownlist controls.

Comment: asp:CascadingDropDown is where one selected value in one drop down controls the values available to select in the next drop down list. As suggested in  Tetsuya Yamamoto reply, I added the asp:UpdatePanel as wrapper around my  drop down list. But now when I click the add to Db button, nothing happens. Looks like it does not call the OnClick event ButtonTotalingLevelB_Click. Can you please clarify what do I have to put in the IsPostBack.